# batch update mysql table

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table with a column called time, "HH:MM:SS". How can I do a batch update so that the value increment by 1 hour?

Is it something like:

```
update <table_name> set <time_column> = <time_column> + 3600 where ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your `time_column` is a string (varchar/etc), use the [ADDTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime) function to increment the time value by an hour:

```
UPDATE table_name
   SET time_column = ADDTIME(time_column, '01:00:00')
 WHERE ...
```

Comment: the time column is a 'time'.. what shld i do, then?